# Use batch file or Powershell to count the number of files with image in them?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a number of word and pdf documents in a folder. I want to pick each document to read it, and as soon as an image is detected in the file, the file is exited and a count of the fileWithImage is updated in a particular text file or so.
Is it possible using a batch file or a PowerShell code?

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe not the most elegant way of doing it, but it works for inline and floating images in Word documents.

As is this example deals with only one file, you will need to add a Get-Childitem and replace "word.docx" with each found item's fullname.

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$word.Visible = $false

$doc = $word.documents.open("word.docx")

$found = $false

for ($i = 1; $i -le $doc.InlineShapes.Count; $i++)
{
    if ($doc.InlineShapes.Item($i).type -eq 3)
    {
        $found = $true
        break
    }
}
if (!$found)
{
    for ($i = 1; $i -le $doc.Shapes.Count; $i++)
    {
        if ($doc.Shapes.Item($i).type -eq 13)
        {
            $found = $true
            break
        }
    }
}
$word.Quit()
$found
```

[Source VBA](http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/05/06/word-vba-loop-through-images/)